# How to detach audio stream bitrate from video file in Android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, media, android-audiomanager

I want to get audio bitrate from video file and save it. 
Is it possible to get audio track bitrate alone form video file using ffmpeg ?
if possible then how to do it?...Any suggestion will be appreciated.